# Pokemon always flee when I try catching

Tags: pokemon-go

I tried catching like 20+ Pokemon, but when I throw the Pokeball, it ticks 1 time, and they run, even though they are CP 10.

I'm currently level 17. What's wrong?

Comment: You may be softbanned. If so, this should resolve itself in a few hours for you.

Comment: how long time does softbanned take?

Comment: As in, you may be softbanned from Pokemon GO.

Comment: I play on Computer, so i can teleport, but only teleporting around in 1 city.

Comment: So this is like a warning? Or can u only get softbanned?

Comment: Yes, I figured. Teleporting is likely to get you softbanned for moving around too quickly, since it is in effect cheating. When this happens, you will be unable to catch any Pokemon or use any Pokestops. At the moment, it seems Niantic is only issuing (likely automated) softbans, but they have in the past issued hard bans, in the Pokemon GO beta and in their previous ARG Ingress.

Comment: So right now u can only get softbanned for teleporting?

Comment: Oh, I'm sure you _can_ get hardbanned. We just haven't heard it happening yet. But there's nothing stopping Niantic from doing so, at any time, for any reason.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would suggest reporting it as a problem to the company VIA support, but the game is new, has thousands of bugs in it, and the Devs have much much more to do than fix than your account.
Try playing another game,then coming back to it.The Gym battle bug.The GPS Bug. The Rubberband Bug. The double account bug. Just to name a few. Give them time to cure. At least a week.

I recommend Ingress, it is somewhat similar and has almost no bugs. It is made by the same company. I had problems with GO, so a friend recommended it to me. I already like it a lot better than GO.